# How to render(or convert) a composable to image in compose-desktop

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

As the title says, hot to render a composable to image.
I want to render a composable to image on my server and send it to client

I have try for these code, but it does not work.

```kotlin
SwingUtilities.invokeLater {
    val composePanel = ComposePanel()
    composePanel.setSize(2000,2000)
    composePanel.setContent {
        MaterialTheme {
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)
            ) {
                Text("asdasdsad")
            }
        }
    }
    val bounds = Rectangle()
    composePanel.getBounds(bounds)
    val img = BufferedImage(
        (bounds.getX() + bounds.getWidth()).toInt(),
        (bounds.getY() + bounds.getHeight()).toInt(),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB
    )
    composePanel.print(img.graphics)
    val out = File("test.png")
    out.delete()
    ImageIO.write(img, "png", out)
}
```

Comment: Try the screenshot API from the testing library, it took some [tinkering](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/issues/2520) but we have that working pretty reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found a solution.The code below works fine.

But I didn't find a better way to direct convert `Image` to `BufferedImage`.

```
val scene = ImageComposeScene(
    width = 2000, // Or whatever you need
    height = 2000, // Or whatever you need
    density = Density(3f), // Or whatever you need
    coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Unconfined
) {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)
        ) {
            Text("asdasdsad")
        }
    }
}
val img = scene.render()

val bitmap = Bitmap.makeFromImage(img)
val bufferedImage = bitmap.toBufferedImage()
val out = File("test.png")
out.delete()
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", out)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, on JetBrains Compose 1.5.10, calling `toBufferedImage()` on the result from `Bitmap.makeFromImage(scene.render())` is leading to an `UnsupportedOperationException` being thrown with this error message:

> unsupported color type RGBA_8888

Here's what worked for me:

```kotlin
val scene = ImageComposeScene(
    width = 2000, // Or whatever you need
    height = 2000, // Or whatever you need
    density = Density(1f), // Or whatever you need
    coroutineContext = Dispatchers.Unconfined
) {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)
        ) {
            Text("asdasdsad")
        }
    }
}
val img = scene.render()

val bitmap = Bitmap.makeFromImage(img)
val data = Image.makeFromBitmap(bitmap).use { image ->
    image.encodeToData(EncodedImageFormat.PNG)!!
}
val out = File("test.png")
out.delete() // If you want to overwrite like that
out.writeBytes(data.bytes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using JUnit. Add this line to your `build.gradle.kts` file to include the testing library:

```
implementation(compose("org.jetbrains.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4"))
```

To use it:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalTestApi::class)
fun renderScreenshot(width: Int, height: Int) = runDesktopComposeUiTest(width, height) {
    setContent {
        MyComposableToRender()
    }
    val img: Image = captureToImage()
    val file = File("test-screenshot.png")
    val encodedImage = img.encodeToData(EncodedImageFormat.PNG) ?: error("Could not encode image as png")
    file.writeBytes(encodedImage.bytes)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But actually, I want to render it on production build.  : (

Comment: This will still work just fine on a production build, it's just using JUnit to accomplish it.